# CodeProject C# bitstream class gives zero arrays

Tags: c#, stream, bitstream

I'm trying to convert a chunk of data from 8-bit packing to 7-bit packing using Bill Koukoutsis' BitStream library from CodeProject.com which still seems to be the go-to source for this kind of thing in C#. The code I'm using is as follows (fs is a filestream initialized outside of the code):

```
for (int block = 0; block < count; block++)
{
    var theBlock = fetcher(block);
    if (theBlock.Any(x => (x != 0)))
    {
        Console.Write("Good Block =>");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Zero block =>");
    }
    var sevenBitSize = theBlock.Length - (theBlock.Length/8);
    var theCodedBlock = new byte[sevenBitSize];
    var ms = new MemoryStream(theCodedBlock);
    BitStream bms = ms;
    using (bms)
    {
        foreach (byte t in theBlock)
        {
            bms.Write(t, 0, 7);
        }
        bms.WriteTo(fs);
    }
    if (theCodedBlock.Any(x => (x != 0)))
    {
         Console.Write("Good Block\n");
    }
    else
    {
         Console.Write("Zero block\n");
    }
}
```

When run, this produces a constant stream of "Good Block => Zero Block". So for some reason the BitStream is outputting zeroes into the theCodedBlock array. It seems to work ok for reading values from a memory array elsewhere in the code, so am I doing something wrong or is this a BitStream bug?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem:

The `BitStream` library doesn't properly support writing to the stream it's loaded from; it writes to its internal buffer but doesn't do anything to write it back to the stream. You have to create an empty `BitStream`, write to that, then convert it back to `MemoryStream`.